# Save java object to internal memory asynchroneously?

Tags: java, android, file, object

I need to save a java object to internal memory (a high-level collection of different server responses if to be specific). Now I use this code:

```
public void write(Context context) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(BACKSTACK_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(backStack);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.t("failed to write backstack: " + e.toString()); e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (fos != null) fos.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

public void read(Context context) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(BACKSTACK_FILENAME);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Deque<FragmentInfo> list = (Deque<FragmentInfo>) ois.readObject();
        L.t(list.toString());
        backStack = list;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        L.t("failed to read backstack" + e.toString()); e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (fis != null) fis.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Since we have context here, UI thread hangs(lags) white operation is performed.
And the larger object becomes, the worse it looks. So the question is:

**Is there any way to save java object to internal memory asynchroneously?**

Please don't recommend to use a database for such a simple task.

Comment: Use an AsyncTask...

Comment: Or a `Thread`..

Answer (score 1):

Saving to internal memory won't help.  The real problem is that you are doing too much work on the event listener thread.  You will have the same problem if you save lots of stuff to a file, a database, "internal memory" .... or to anything else.  Serialization is relatively expensive no matter how you do it, and no matter where you save the results of the serialization.

The solution is to do the work using an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: So it won't hang(lag) the UI if I use AsyncTask even if I need a context to work with file? Please, offer a code snippet.

Comment: 1)  Correct.  (At least ... to a first approximation ...) 2) Surely Google can help you with that .....